# Is it possible to send more info via get token call from client in a WEB API application?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, access-token

For my WebAPI project OAuth handling, I have the following codes:

```
namespace Synergetic.API.WebAPI
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            //app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
                AllowInsecureHttp = true


            };




            // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);            
        }
    }
}
```

There is also an Application subclassed from OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider that actually uses this method.

In the web client side I have this javascript for getting the token from server:

```
var token;
var loginData = {
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: $('#txtUser').val(),
            password: $('#txtPassword').val()
        };
        var beforeSendFunc = function (request) {
            //alert(token);
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "Token",
            data: loginData
        }).success(function (data) {
       .............
```

UPDATE: Having done some investigation,I am assuming it is not possible or at least hard to achieve to have more than one token access endpoint for an authorisation server. Can we instead send more information through get token client call?, I mean more data in addition to existing username, password, credential?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found this useful thread:

[How do you consume extra parameters in OAuth2 Token request within .net WebApi2 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243996/how-do-you-consume-extra-parameters-in-oauth2-token-request-within-net-webapi2)

We need to add the following line of code to the OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions method:

```
 var data = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
```