# How to pass other parameters to OWIN Login?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I've got an ASP.NET Web API site, which is doing OWIN authentication, passing username and password, which magically appear in my `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method, inside the `UserName` and `Password` properties of the `OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext` parameter.  No idea how this works, but it does.

Anyway, now I want to pass another parameter to the login method, which I'd like to access in that same `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method.  But since I don't know how this magic works, that takes the `UserName` and `Password` parameters from the login request and copies them to the `OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext` parameter, I have no idea now how I could get access to my new parameter.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
//read all parameters
IFormCollection parameters = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();

if (parameters == null)
{
    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Invalid request");
    return;
}
//get desired parameter
var deviceId = parameters.Get("device_id");
//check if it was send
if (deviceId == null)
{
    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "parameter 'device_id' is required");
    return;
}
```

Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21244952/965722

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't find any way to do it using regular POST body parameters, so I added the parameter to the header, where it is available through the `context.Request.Headers` collection.

This is my answer for now; if anyone has a way to do this the normal way, through the POST body, I'd love to hear it.